# Sinon spy on switch statement

Tags: unit-testing, sinon, spy

Is there a way to spy / stub a switch statement? I tried:

```
let spy = sandbox.spy(global, 'switch');
```

But that does not work unfortunately.

Comment: In this case, you will need to extract your switch statement into its own function.

Answer (score 1):

No. A `switch` is a language-level control statement and can't be affected like this.

This is no setback, however. You should be testing *what* your units do, not *how* they do it. This distinction can be a little muddy sometimes, but in this case? The presence or absence of a `switch` in a function is going to be a 'how' and not a 'what' 100% of the time. In other words, its an implementation detail.

If you're to the point where you *want* something like this, I'd recommend taking a step back and really thinking about why you want it. Do you really want tests to fail if you replace a `switch` with an equivalent chain of if/else-if/else? Probably not.